# golang test fails on flags parse for test.v

Tags: go, testing, flags, goland, go-testing

In my go program, the main method does:

```
port := flag.Int("port", 8080, "Port number to start service on")
flag.Parse()
```

I have a dummy test that looks as:

```
func TestName(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Hello there")
}
```

when I run my tests (from the goland or the command line) I got the following error stuck:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go tool test2json -t /private/var/folders/7v/p2t5phhn6cn9hqwjnn_p95_80000gn/T/___TestName_in_github_tools....test -test.v -test.paniconexit0 -test.run ^\QTestName\E$
flag provided but not defined: -test.v
Usage of /private/var/folders/7v/p2t5phhn6cn9hqwjnn_p95_80000gn/T/___TestName_in_github_tools.....test:
  -port int
        Port number to start service on (default 8080)
```

When I remove the lines of the flag in the main, the test executes normally
Any idea on how to fix this, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. You _exacty_ do you run your tests? A simple (and correct)  `go test` or some fancyness? 2. Why do you call testing.Init()? Which part of testing.Init's documentation made you think your code would benefit from it. 3. Your `func main()` is not called during execution of test so any modification of the global execution space (like what flag.Int does) is not executed.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you meant to ask 'how exactly do you run your tests?'
Actually, I do 'go test' the call for testing.Init() was here by mistake I will edit the test

Comment: Are you sure that you pass `flag.Parse()` to the `main()` function? It can happen if you pass it to `init()` function. Please see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859, especially https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859#issuecomment-489889428

Comment: If you are doing 'go test' why are you passing -test.v flag? Please add details on how you are running tests to the question.

Comment: test2json is not normaly called by running `go test`. Sou are not running a simple `go test`. Please include the _exact_ command line you use to run your tests in the question.

Comment: I execute "go test" and I get: "flag provided but not defined: -test.paniconexit0"

Comment: Please, provide a full code snippet from your `main.go` and `filename_test.go`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `go test`, go actually compiles your code into an executable, and executes it.
If you add options to `go test` -- for example : `go test -v` -- these options are actually passed to the test executable, prefixed with `test` -- so `-v` is turned into `-test.v`.

(this is a reason why several comments ask for the exact command line you use to run your tests : since the error is about `-test.v`, there probably is something that adds `-v` to some `go test ...` invocation)

---

It looks like `flag.Parse()` is trying to parse some arguments which are actually intended for your test executable, not for your code.

This is probably because it is called too early, before the test executable has had a chance to alter the `os.Args` slice to remove some specific flags.

Check what triggers a call to `flag.Parse()` : if it is executed from an `init()` block, this would count as "too early".

---

The behavior of `go test` options is documented in [`go help testflag`](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/test/#HelpTestflag) :

> Each of these flags is also recognized with an optional 'test.' prefix,
> as in -test.v. When invoking the generated test binary (the result of
> 'go test -c') directly, however, the prefix is mandatory.
>
> The 'go test' command rewrites or removes recognized flags,
> as appropriate, both before and after the optional package list,
> before invoking the test binary.
>
> For instance, the command
>
> ```
> go test -v -myflag testdata -cpuprofile=prof.out -x
> ```
>
> will compile the test binary and then run it as
>
> ```
> pkg.test -test.v -myflag testdata -test.cpuprofile=prof.out
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed this was the issue.
I found a call to the flag.parse somewhere before the main function in my code, removed it and everything works as expected

Comment: We can also add following code before flag.Parse() method in init() block 

var _ = func() bool {
  testing.Init()
  return true
 }()

It will initialize the required test flags.